# C# Add element to existing XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml

Answers to similar questions aren't helping me; or I'm missing something very obvious.

I want to add a `<value>` element into a `<question>` element in XML structured like this:

```
<form>
    <foo>
        <bar>
            <question id="1">...</question>
            <question id="2">...</question>
        </bar>
    </foo>
</form>
```

Other questions seem to focus on adding an element into the root element but I'm trying to add mine further into the tree based on attribute values. I have tried the following which doesn't work:

```
XDocument newFormTemplateXML = XDocument.Load("newFormTemplate.xml");
XElement newValue = new XElement("value", 123);
newFormTemplateXML
    .Descendants()
    .Where(d => d.Name.ToString().Equals("question") && d.Attribute("id").Equals(1))
    .Append(newValue);
newFormTemplateXML.Save("test.xml");
```

I'm not getting an error message. Can someone help me on the right path please?

Comment: Try to use "Add" instead of "Append". By the way is newValue element inserted somewhere?

Comment: Also, take a look to this  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a3738fd0-75a9-4d74-b1a1-37cc8851c3e8/c-add-xml-child-node-to-specific-parent?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: I've tried Add() to no avail - except for adding newValue to the root with `newFormTemplateXML.Root.Add(newValue)`

Comment: `newFormTemplateXML.Descendants("question").Where(q => (int) q.Attribute("id") == 1).Single().Add(new XElement("boo"))` works for me.

Comment: @JeroenMostert ooo that worked, thank you - do you want to post that up as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the "native" methods:

```
newFormTemplateXML
    .Descendants("question")
    .Single(q => (int) q.Attribute("id") == 1)
    .Add(newValue);
```

Or, for XPath lovers:

```
newFormTemplateXML.XPathSelectElement("//question[@id=1]").Add(newValue);
```

Note that this doesn't verify there is really only one question with `id` 1, it will modify only the first such question. The `Single()` call doesn't have this problem/advantage.

Answer (score 0):

[Append](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.append?view=netframework-4.7.2) doesn't do what you think it does. Append adds a new item to the end of a sequence and you are not wanting to add to the descendants.

```
XDocument newFormTemplateXML = XDocument.Load("newFormTemplate.xml");
XElement newvalue = new XElement("value", 123);
var question = newFormTemplateXML.Descendants()
    .Where(d => d.Name.ToString().Equals("question") &&   
        d.Attribute("id").Equals(1)).SingleOrDefault();
question.add(newValue)
newFormTemplateXML.Save("test.xml");
```